# Generating vector geospatial PDF from ArcGIS Server services

Tags: arcgis-server, fme-form, style, pdf, geospatial-pdf

I am exploring possibilities to generate vector geospatial PDF from data which is accessible from ArcGIS Server services. I have ArcGIS Server MapService with complex styles. They are very simplified in FeatureService - so that is not an option.

I have already tried to use **Export Map** operation of MapService and was lucky to get nicely styled vector PDF from it. Of course, I have coordinates of a BoundBox (this info actually is used for querying).

So, now I need to include additional data (some labels, borders and other pre-print graphic) and generate result PDF. It seems like a task for FME Desktop. But I have not found how I can import input PDF from http query. In fact it seems that I can't even open PDF from disk in FME; it is capable only to write it.

What possible solutions do you see for this task?

The key thing is to keep complex styling from ArcGIS Server. I can also access the mxd which was used for creation of the service.

I need solution which is possible to run from scripts, as it will be scheduled task. Maybe there is a solution to combine several PDF files into one in Python? Some advanced Python lib for editing PDFs?

Comment: FME only Writes PDF (Geo or Plain) - http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/

Comment: Yep, I have already realized that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for this problem.

At last I had to simplify my task for this time. Instead of generating GeoPDF I have decided to generate well designed PDF file for print purpose with labels, borders and other pre-print graphics.

It was successfully performed using Geoprocessing service for ArcGIS Server and [arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/) module for scripting additional complex logic.

Nice example to start from can be found here: [ExportToPDF Geoprocessing Service Example](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=442e1c7ff64240af8f41825f567e60d0)

Answer (score 0):

FME will read an MXD dataset. Will that help?

Comment: I have already tried this way and performed export to PDF, but it seems that during process of reading MXD in FME some complex styles are simplified - this is not very good :(